# Make Bootstrap 4 navbar search box stretch the all across the available space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a Bootstrap 4 navigation bar which contains, from left to right:

1. The Logo (brand)
2. A search bar
3. The website's navigation

I want the search box stretch the all across the space available between the logo and navigation. My code so far:

```css
.navbar {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #191919;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 47px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu a {
  padding: 11px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  color: #757575;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: #555;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu a:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .form-inline {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
.navbar-inverse .form-inline .bg-white {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  height: 37px;
}
.navbar-inverse .btn-outline-secondary {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .btn-outline-secondary:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #0275D8;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 56px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-primary">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <form class="form-inline mx-auto">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control border-right-0" placeholder="Search here...">
        <span class="input-group-addon bg-white border-left-0"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 Categories</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sports</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hot</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mad Science</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My account</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus mollitia, minima aliquam soluta ducimus sint obcaecati rerum inventore, ipsa nobis dignissimos, reiciendis, numquam cum sit cumque suscipit voluptatibus a est?</p>
</div>
```

The search box is too small, as you can see on a *wide screen*. I wish it's *left side was 15px from the logo* and it's *right side was 15px from the navigation*. What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using Bootstrap 4 *alpha* which is now **totally outdated**.

Also, you don't want to use the `form-inline` class when you want the form input to span full width. That class is designed precisely to *prevent* form inputs from spanning full width.

Here's a complete, working code snippet that does what you want (you'll have to adjust the colors as needed):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-wrap2 flex-md-nowrap p-0">
<!--        <div class="container-fluid">-->
        <a class="navbar-brand col-auto mr-0" href="#">Brand</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler d-md-none mt-1 mr-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="input-group py-1 px-2 px-md-0">
            <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" placeholder="Search here..." aria-label="Search">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-md pl-2 pr-3">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-nowrap">
                    <li class="nav-item my-1 active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown my-1">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Categories
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sports</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hot</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mad Science</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item my-1">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My account</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ul>
<!--        </div>-->
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You'll probably want to wrap the whole thing in a `container` or `container-fluid`. In that case, just uncomment the corresponding div.

Also notice the use of responsive padding and margin classes to control the spacing. For example, `my-1` give the navbar items vertical margin of 1 unit and `px-2 px-md-0` provides horizontal padding (to the input-group) of 2 units from the smallest screens onwards while at the same time reducing the horizontal padding to zero from medium (md) screens onwards.